# Pandas Column Names Not Lining Up When .dat File Read

Tags: python, pandas

I'm going through Wes McKinney's Python for Data Analysis 2nd Edition and in Chapter 2 he has several examples based of merging three `.dat` files about movie reviews.

I can get two of the three data files to work (users and reviews), but the third one (movie titles) I can not get to work and can't figure out what to do.

Here's the code:

```
mnames = ['movie_id', 'title', 'genres']
movies = pd.read_table('movies.dat',  sep = '::', header = None, engine = 'python', names = mnames)

print(movies[:5])
```

And here is what the output/problem looks like. Seems the file is not lining up the separator correctly and I've tried recreating the file and comparing to the other two files which are working but they look exactly the same.
[image]

Here's a sample data taken from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/2nd-edition/datasets/movielens/movies.dat):

```
1::Toy Story (1995)::Animation|Children's|Comedy
2::Jumanji (1995)::Adventure|Children's|Fantasy
3::Grumpier Old Men (1995)::Comedy|Romance
4::Waiting to Exhale (1995)::Comedy|Drama
5::Father of the Bride Part II (1995)::Comedy
6::Heat (1995)::Action|Crime|Thriller
7::Sabrina (1995)::Comedy|Romance
8::Tom and Huck (1995)::Adventure|Children's
9::Sudden Death (1995)::Action
10::GoldenEye (1995)::Action|Adventure|Thriller
11::American President, The (1995)::Comedy|Drama|Romance
12::Dracula: Dead and Loving It (1995)::Comedy|Horror
13::Balto (1995)::Animation|Children's
14::Nixon (1995)::Drama
```

I'd like to be able to read this file properly so I can join it to the other two example files and keep learning Pandas :)

Comment: For me working nice.

Comment: post a link to your raw .dat file it looks like you have some strange encoding or BOM at the beginning

Comment: Here's the link, thank you both for helping me: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LyO92zGESOpqOgSeLIGUhwbElCqhYRW6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding  `encoding='UTF-16'` to `pd.read_table()`

(Sorry, not enough reputation to add a comment.)